# Framework vs writing from scratch

Tags: php, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use a framework with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851920/why-use-a-framework-with-php)

I am a php developer and always writing my code from scratch, but I am hearing lot about these frameworks of php (CodeIgniter, CakePHP and others).

The main reason I am worried about is that using, will using frameworks help me in a long run?

Specifically what I am wondering about is: When working on a bigger project with a large infrastructure and a lot of content, is it wise to use a framework, or should the code be written by scratch?

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=framework+php

Answer (score 2):

While I am not a big fan of most PHP frameworks (probably because I'm used to the python ones which usually don't even need (much) generated code), they will most likely make you write cleaner and more structured code.

Besides that, some basic functions like user authentication might already be provided by your framework.